# Let $S$ be an infinite set. Then there is a set $A\subset S$ such that $A\sim \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

This proof seems to follow very quickly from the definition of infinite sets, but I feel like what I have is incomplete:

Since $S$ is infinite, we have that $S\sim \mathbb{N}$. By definition, $S$ is equinumerous to a proper subset of itself. Let $A\subset S$ be such a set. Hence, $A\sim S$. Thus, $A\sim S\sim \mathbb{N}$, so $A\sim \mathbb{N}$. Thus, there is some $A\subset S$ such that $A\sim \mathbb{N}$.

It's one of those "that seems way to easy" situations. Is this proof "too good to be true?" :)

Comment: Your sentence beginning with "Since $\;S\;$ is infinite..." is false. For example, $\;\Bbb R\;$ is infinite but $\;\Bbb R\rlap{\;\,/.}\sim\Bbb N\;$

Comment: Good point. So should I still be using the fact that $S$ is equinumerous to a proper subset of itself?

Comment: @kanker7 You can try that (it is true), yet perhaps you could try  *choosing* a "list" of elements: take any $\;s_1\in S\;$ , then choose $\;s_2\in S\setminus\{s_1\}\;$ , which exists since $\;S\;$ is infinite, and etc.

Comment: @NoahSchweber its close, but I think there's a difference between a set being infinite and a set being denumerable.

Comment: @kanker7 The linked post by Noah is **exactly** the same you want.

Comment: @Joanpemo wouldn't we then need to invoke the Axiom Of Choice? I.e. how do we know what $s_1\in S$ to take away?

Comment: @kanker7 Yes, you need (a small amount of) choice here; the statement in question is **not provable** in ZF alone! Look up e.g. **amorphous sets**.

Comment: @kanker7 That was in my first version in that comment, yet I'm not sure we actually need it here since we use only the fact that $\;S\;$ is infinite, and we choose *any* element there and call it $\;s_1\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo : You don't need AC to chose $s_1$, or any $s_n$. But you **need** AC to chose them all at the same time (and you need to do that to have your set)